# Returning data from asynchronous url connection to caller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to have my class (the "caller") send a message to a controller object to return data gathered from an NSURLConnection asynchronously. i.e., I want the caller to be able to do something like `NSData * myData = [urlconnectioncontroller getData];` without having the caller implement the NSURLConnection delegate methods itself. Something tells me this isn't possible. I suppose I could implement something like `[urlconnectioncontroller requestDataWithCallback:(SEL)callback]` and then have the caller implement the `callback` method that would receive the data upon the NSURLConnection calling the `connectionDidFinishLoading` delegate method. I'm not sure this is the best way to do this type of thing, though. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks/callback is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, i was afraid of that. I guess that's not so bad :)

Comment: Blocks make this very simple.

Comment: See ASIHTTPRequest. It has a good implementation of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `NSURLConnection` and it's delegate methods. It's all there - three methods:

1. for beginning the connection (used for allocating data pool like `NSMutableData` instance var)
2. for gathering data (called repeatedly on each received data chunk)
3. for finishing the connection (doing something with actually received data)

And a couple ones for insurance just in case connection failed at the beginning or timed out.

Comment: I know how the delegate methods work. I have them implemented in a controller object that does all the nitty-gritty nsurlconnection work. What I want is to provide an interface to this controller object so that other object can simply and easily request information and get it back. I don't want to have to implement delegate methods in a whole bunch of different places in my code.

Comment: This role should not be in controller. You should implement separate class for this used as a model (the M in MVC).

Comment: Fair enough, this probably should be classified as Model. But regardless, you see what I'm trying to do here, yeah?

Comment: Yes. I'd suggest using those delegate methods along with some sort of connection or owner identifier to whom return the data once it's been fetched (via notifications or via passed delegate object's method call).

Comment: also, as @ssteinberg wrote - the blocks would be a huge help for this.

Comment: Okay, yeah. I figured that might be the only way.